# MySQL count number of occurrences of field value with join data

Tags: mysql, join, count

I have 2 tables in my database, see below:

Events Table

```
title | venue_id
event 1 | 1
event 2 | 1
event 3 | 1
event 4 | 1
event 5 | 2
event 6 | 2
event 7 | 2
event 8 | 2
event 9 | 3
event 10 | 3
```

Venues Table

```
id | title
1  | Venue 1
2  | Venue 2
3  | Venue 3
```

The desired results I am looking for would be

```
venue_title | event_count
Venue 1     | 4
Venue 2     | 4
Venue 3     | 2
```

I have been trying to do this with joins but for some reason I am getting the count 1 back for every venue.

This is what my SQL looks like just now.

```
SELECT
  count(DISTINCT events.venue_id),
  venues.title,
FROM
  events
INNER JOIN
  venues
  ON venues.id = events.venue_id
```

I have looked around various over SO posts but unable to find anything that has been able to help.  I am really a beginner at SQL like this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `group by` clause:

```
SELECT
  count(DISTINCT events.venue_id),
  venues.title,
FROM
  events
INNER JOIN
  venues
  ON venues.id = events.venue_id
GROUP BY -- Here!
  venues.id, venutes.title
```

Comment: It should be `GROUP BY venutes.title`

Comment: This worked with the tweak from @RaymondNijland too.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- You can do a `group by` on `events` table, get the results and do an inner join of this obtained result with `venues` table. This can also improve performance of inner join since it will have to map fewer number of rows.

**SQL:**

```
select v.title,derived.event_count
from venues v
inner join (select venue_id,count(venue_id) as event_count
from events 
group by venue_id) derived
on v.id = derived.venue_id
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use GROUP BY and HAVING clause

```
SELECT
      count(events.venue_id),venues.title,
    FROM events
    INNER JOIN venues
      ON venues.id = events.venue_id group by events.venue_id having count(events.venue_id) > 0
```

The GROUP BY Clause is used to group rows with same values and HAVING clause is used to restrict the results returned by the GROUP BY clause.

so `> 0` return the duplicate values having count > 0

Comment: your explainment about `having count(events.venue_id) > 0` duplicate part is not correct.. if you want to filter duplicates you use `having count(distinct ...) > <value>`.. but i doubt the topicstarter need to remove/filer duplicates.

Comment: @RaymondNijland thank's for clarifying. the topic is about displaying  "count number of occurrences of field value with join data"  so `having count(events.venue_id) > 0` populate the count. do we really need `distinct` in having